# Determine if columns in postgres table are inherited

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to list out the columns in a child table and see which ones are inherited from the parent table and which ones are defined on the child table.

```sql
SELECT column_name, inheritied
FROM column_view
WHERE table_name = 'a_child_table'
```

```
------------------------------------
| column_name       |  inherited   |
------------------------------------
| foobar            |      f       |
------------------------------------
| whizbang          |      t       |
------------------------------------
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query uses `pg_inherits`, which tracks table inheritance:

```
SELECT a.attname,
       EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM pg_inherits AS i
             JOIN pg_attribute AS a2
                ON i.inhparent = a2.attrelid
             WHERE i.inhrelid = a.attrelid
               AND a.attname = a2.attname
       ) AS inherited
FROM pg_attribute AS a
WHERE a.attrelid = 'tablename'::regclass
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

Comment: Thanks! you're missing a comma after `a.attname` but otherwise is what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks for testing, fixed.